# ng-click and ng-disabled to do 'add to cart' function

Tags: jquery, angularjs, http, angularjs-scope, shopping-cart

I need help dynamically enabling and disabling my 'add to cart' button but right now once I click on 'add to cart' it doesn't disable the button right away but I have to click on the blank canvas to get it disabled.

HTML

```
<div id="shoppingCart">
    <form name="addItemsForm" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" name="type" value="Package" />
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="df in item.delivery_formats">
                    <button type="button" name="addToCartBtn" id="{{df.price_id}}" 
                     value="{{df.price_id}}" class="btn btn-default" ng-model="$parent.addToCartBtn" 
ng-click="addToCart(df.price_id, df);" ng-disabled="checkBtnState(df.button_state)"/> <span class="fa fa-shopping-cart" style="float: left;"></span>  <strong>{{df.delivery_format}} -  ${{df.price}}</strong>

                    </button>
                </li>
            </ul>
    </form>
</div>
```

Angular & JS

```
$scope.checkBtnState = function(btn_state){
  if(btn_state == 'disabled') {
    return true;
  }
  else {
    return false;
  }
}
$scope.addToCart = function(id, dfObj){
  $http({
    url: "/shop/add.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: {id: id}
  })
  .success(function(){
    $('#cart').load('/php/cart-items.php');
    dfObj.button_state = 'disabled';
  })
  .error(function(){
    alert('error');
  });
}
```

Comment: I don't get, you are disabling it in the 'then' part and expecting the value 'button_state' to be updated immediately !!!

Answer (score 2):

Its very trivial though - put it outside of the promise.

```
$scope.addToCart = function(id, dfObj){
    $http({
        url: "/shop/add.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: {id: id}
    }).then(function(){
        $('#cart').load('/php/cart-items.php');           
    })
    .error(function(){
        alert('error');
    });
    dfObj.button_state = 'disabled';
}
```